# Cake Php: Editing record also adds new records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i am trying to soft delete a record, but when ever i update the record i also get 6 new empty records. here is my edit code

```
public function del($id = null){
    $dt = $this->Store->findById($id);

    $dt["Store"]["status"] = 0;

    if($this->Store->save($dt)){
        $this->Session->setFlash("Your Store has been Deleted");
        $this->redirect("/stores/");
    }
}
```

Comment: i also tried
$this->Store->id = $id;
$this->Store->saveField('status',0);

but no difference in result

Comment: @nathan, i was trying different tricks i could find on internet to get it to work, so it was one of these and it was there when i copied the code here.

using this makes no difference in result. i am going to remove it from here for now

Comment: Can you add the code of you Store model and the definition of the database-table?

Answer (score 0):

As you describe in your question updated function will sure help you

```
public function del($id = null){
$dt = $this->Store->findById($id);

$dt["Store"]["id"] = $dt['Store']['id'];
// or

   $dt["Store"]["id"] = $id // not empty every time.

   $dt["Store"]["status"] = 0;

if($this->Store->save($dt)){
    $this->Session->setFlash("Your Store has been Deleted");
    $this->redirect("/stores/");
}
```

}

Comment: it adds empty records in database also

Comment: will you describe your Table structure. ?

Answer (score 0):

Set id for Store model, then use saveField.

```
public function del($store_id)
{
    $this->Store->id = $store_id;
    $this->Store->saveField('status', 0);
    $this->redirect('/stores/');
}
```